# Add property to model of other app in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on a project that should be deployed to several different clients with slightly different configurations and features. To achieve that, for each feature I wanted to create a new app in django. As an example we have one base app which contains a model for `Patient` (pretty simple, name, id, ...). For some clients I would like to create a parent app that will include an additional app called `case_type` which contains a model called `CaseType`. In that app one patient can have one caseType.

But here is the catch. The `patient` app should work with or without the `case_type` app. Therefore I would like to kind of "inject" a new property into the model and serializer of `Patient` from within the `case_type` app. So this way when deploying with the `case_type` app the user will receive a JSON like this when calling `/patient/<id>`:

```
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "id": "123",
  "caseType": {
    "type": "a",
    "comment": "something"
  }
}
```

but when calling the same route without the `case_type` app I want it to return

```
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "id": "123"
}
```

This means I will have to dynamically adapt the serializer and model in a "dependency-injection"-kind of way. There are multiple cases, where such a use-case would make sense for this application.
I could just reference the `case_type` model in the respective app but that would result in having to adapt the code itself for each client and creating a lot of duplicated code (one patient app WITH the case_type, one without).

Do you have any other idea of how to solve such a modularization problem in django?

Answer (score 0):

By "should be deployed to several different clients" I understand you'll have a single code base and different environments for each deploy.

Assuming this, I'd go with the following approach:

- Model your dependent apps and models in such a way that `case_type` would depend on `patients` but not the other way around, by having the `patient` reference on `CaseType` model

```
class CaseType(models.Model):
  ...
  patient = models.OneToOneField(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='case_type')
```

- For the patient's serializer, you can have the class dynamically created based on the environment:

```
class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
     model = Patient
     fields = PatientSerializer.generate_fields()

  @staticmethod
  def generate_fields():
    fields = ['id', 'name']
    if os.environ.get('CASE_TYPE', False):
      fields.append('case_type')
```